# Extjs 3.4 - Ajax call being cancelled automatically

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

I have a PHP script the imports a large file into a DB.
When I execute the script directly, it completes without a problem.
However, when I call the same script in my extjs app, it fails with:
`transaction aborted` captured by the Ajax failure callback.

The Ajax request:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: projectparameters.service + 'importxxxxx.php',
            scope: this,
            method: "POST",
            params: {
                projectparameters: JSON.stringify(projectparameters),
                ftpUrl: ftpUrl,
                fileName: fileName,
                fileDate: fileDate
            },
            success: function(response, rowIndex){

                var feedback = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                if(feedback.success === false) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', feedback.msg);
                }
                else if( feedback.success === true ) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', feedback.msg);
                    // After uploading the file - reload import-history
                    var importHistoryTab = Ext.getCmp('grid_ImportHistory');
                    importHistoryTab.getStore().reload();
                    var featureGrid = Ext.getCmp("featuregrid");
                    featureGrid.getStore().reload();
                }
            },
            failure: function(response, rowIndex){
                console.log('response: ');
                console.log(response);

                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'File could not be imported - '+response.statusText+'.<br> Aborted: '+response.isAbort+'. <br>Timeout: '+response.isTimeout+'.');
            }
    });
```

This is what I can see in the network response:
[image: network-inspection]

This is the Ajax failure object
[image: extjs-resp]

I have already set the script execution to infinity in PHP, so I doubt PHP being the culprit, as I said, executing the script independantly from the frontend works...

**So:** Is this the ajax not being set up correctly? How can I trace this?

Any ideas?

I cannot seem to figure this out or find any helpful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple:
set the `timeout` for the Ajax.

I just had to increase it to allow the script to finish.